# Census transform vs Mutual Information

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, census

I need to use an algorithm for stereo processing images (or frames – as I intend to use it for a real-time application written in C/C++) and I was thinking about:  **Census transform** algorithm and matching cost calculation based on **Mutual Information** as my best options, but as far as I know, Census transform doesn’t give quite as accurate results as Mutual Information, and Mutual Information is more expensive.

Which one would be more suitable for my case?